# Symmetric rank two correction of a symmetric positive definite matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-calculus

Let $P$ is a symmetric positive definite matrix and define $P'$ as follow:

$$P'=P + (e_ie_j^T+e_je_i^t)P_{ij}$$

(where $i \neq j$).

(so $P'$ is a rank 2, symmetric correction for $P$)

Is $P'$ is positive definite as well?

Any comment or reference is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Counterexample.
$$ P \; = \;  
 \left(  \begin{array}{rr}
  5  &  -4  \\
   -4   &  5  
\end{array} 
  \right)  
  $$
$$ P' \; = \;  
 \left(  \begin{array}{rr}
  5  &  -8  \\
   -8   &  5  
\end{array} 
  \right)  
  $$

Another counterexample.
$$ P \; = \;  
 \left(  \begin{array}{rr}
  7  &  6  \\
   6   &  7  
\end{array} 
  \right)  
  $$
$$ P' \; = \;  
 \left(  \begin{array}{rr}
  7  &  12  \\
   12   &  7  
\end{array} 
  \right)  
  $$